# How can I add a recurring timer to a Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, gecko

I am trying to create an addon with the new addons builder preview (https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/), and I need a function to run about once every 10 minutes. I have tried both setInterval and setTimeout, but they both return the following error:

```
    error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid0-31njasqk3btmpa6paroepuybjn4-myaddon-lib/main.js", line 41, in 
    setTimeout(function() { timedCount(); }, 10000);
ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined
```

(with setTimeout being replaced with setInterval when I tried it. The setTimeout function worked great in the similar webpage that I built. I just had the function call itself to give an infinite loop (It sounds stupid, there should be a while loop, but it was in a tutorial;)
But now I can't get past that error in my addon.

Also, if you can help me parse a local or remote page in this addon (preferably remote, but I could make it parse a django-created page on localhost instead), or even better, just tell me how to use python ;) that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: For your parsing question please create a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [timer module](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b3/docs/packages/api-utils/docs/timer.html):

```
var tmr = require('timer');
tmr.setInterval(timedCount, 10000); // no need for an anon function since you don't pass any arguments to your function nor capture anything in a closure
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great! Unfortunately, I still can't do much in that function :(

Answer (score 9):

please note that the above is deprecated

```
var tmr = require('sdk/timers');
```

is now used instead

Answer (score 2):

Use `nsITimer`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITimer

It doesn't require you to use the unnecessary Jetpack SDK, and the extra `require` function; you can use `Components.classes` like you do for other XPCOM interaction within Mozilla addons.