# Getting ReferenceError: setInterval is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to use setInterval() within an extension developed with the firefox add-on sdk.  Unfortunately, no matter how I call setInterval(), I keep getting the ReferenceError that setInterval is not defined.

I've simplified my code to illustrate the problem.  The below code results in this error:

```
var globalTimer = 0;

function setGlobalTimer() {
    globalTimer = setInterval(testFunction, 15000);
    //globalTimer = setInterval(function() { testFunction(); }, 15000);
}

function testFunction() {
    console.log("testFunction just called");    
}

var { ToggleButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/toggle");
var button = ToggleButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    icon: {
      "16": "./icon-16.png",
      "32": "./icon-32.png",
      "64": "./icon-64.png"      
    },
    onClick: handleClick
});


function handleClick(state) {
    testFunction();
    setGlobalTimer();
}
```

Both ways of setting the global variable *globalTimer* in setGlobalTimer(), one way is commented out, result in the following error when I click on my toggle button in Firefox:

> ReferenceError: setInterval is not defined

I've scanned the stackoverflow site for questions about setInterval() not working, and in other cases, using the calls I am using has worked.  But this code generates the above error for me.

If anyone can help me with this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a recurring timer to a firefox addon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248035/how-can-i-add-a-recurring-timer-to-a-firefox-addon)

Comment: Awesome!!  Solved with info from the thread Alexander referenced.

Comment: I used the `var tmr = require('sdk/timers');` solution, and then I set `globalTimer = tmr.setInterval(testFunction, 15000);`

Comment: `setInterval` is implicitly `window.setInterval`. You don't have access to the window object in SDK context.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` is not a global with the add-on sdk at the moment.

you need to require it, like so `var { setInterval } = require("sdk/timers")`