# setInterval not called in tab content-script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Simple use case:

**main.js**

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

tabs.open({
    url: 'http://www.openstreetmap.org',
    onOpen: function (tab) {
        tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: './content.js'
        });
    }
});
```

**content.js**

```
console.log("foo");
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("bar");
}, 1000);
```

**output**

```
foo
```

I get the same problem with event handlers, which is more problematic…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
var { setInterval, clearInterval } = require("sdk/timers");
console.log("foo");
var id = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("bar");
}, 1000);
```

**------------ UPDATE 1 ----------**

This works fine for me:

*main.js*

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var self = require("sdk/self");

tabs.on("ready", function(tab) {

        console.log('opened', self.data.url('content.js'));
        tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: self.data.url('content.js'),
            contentScriptWhen: 'ready'
        });
  })
tabs.open({
    url: 'http://google.com'
});
```

*data/content.js*

```
console.log("foo");

var go = function () {
        console.log('bar');
        window.setTimeout(function () {go();}, 100);
}

window.setTimeout(go, 100)
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/timers)

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248035/how-can-i-add-a-recurring-timer-to-a-firefox-addon)

Comment: My `setTimout` issue is in the content script, which cannot access the require API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

Comment: Ok so actually the only important difference is that you attach the content script when tab is `ready` instead of when tab is `open`. Thx